# How to make my second list appear in correct word order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.4.

This is my code:

```
varSentence = input("What sentence would you like to convert to numbers?" )

varList = varSentence.split()
print (varList)
varList2 = list(set(varList))
print (varList2)

for varCount, varWord in enumerate(varList2):

    for varWord2 in varList:

        if varWord2 == varWord:
            varWord2 = varCount
            print (varCount + 1)
```

Input:

```
varSentence = "this is a test for stack over flow this is a test for stack overflow"

varList = varSentence.split()
 varList2  = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'stack', 'over', 'flow', 'overflow']
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Sets don't guarantee order. It's unclear what output you were expecting from this.

Comment: `varList` and `varList2` are terrible variable names.

Comment: What is the current output you are getting and what is the expected one? Any brief about the code will be good.

Comment: What sentence would you like to convert to numbers?this is a test for stack over flow this is a test for stack overflow 
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'stack', 'over', 'flow', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'stack', 'overflow']
['flow', 'stack', 'for', 'test', 'over', 'overflow', 'a', 'this', 'is']
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
6
7
7
8
8
9
9

Comment: that is what i am getting and i am looking for the numbers to be in order of the words in list 1

Comment: and what variable names would you suggest

Comment: @Remoas your expected output is wrong, it should be `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Please explain problem the code is trying to solve in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just want to add word from `varList` to `varList2` if they are not already there, and then print their rank in `varList2`. You can do everything in one single pass:

```
varSentence = input("What sentence would you like to convert to numbers?" )

varList = varSentence.split()
print (varList)
varList2 = []
ranks = []

for word in varList:
    if word in varList2:
        i = varList2.index(word)
        ranks.append(i+1)
    else:
        varList2.append(word)
        ranks.append(len(varList2))

print varList2
for i in rank:
    print rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OrderedDict if you want to maintain the order of the elements from the original list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
varList2 = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(varList))
# -> ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'stack', 'over', 'flow', 'overflow']
```

Based on your expected output combing with a `Counter` dict would be the best way to go, appending `counts * ind` to a list, the following gives you an `O(n)` solution as opposed to your own quadratic approach:

```
varList = [ 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'stack', 'over', 'flow', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'stack', 'overflow']


from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
counts = Counter(varList)
od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(varList, 0)
res = []
for ind, k in enumerate(od, 1):
    res.extend([ind] *  counts[k])

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you just wanted to print the output just remove the list res:

```
for ind, k in enumerate(od, 1):
    print(*[ind]*v,end=" ")
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```